# Using custom images in components react

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have a react component that is used many times on a products page.  Each of the components has its own image.  Is there a way to dynamically import an image?  For example something like

```
function productPage({imgPath}){
    import img from imgPath
    return <img src={img}/>
}
```

and when I use the component I can do something like

```
<productPage imgPath="/pathToImage">
```

I have only come across answers that use require (`<img src={require("/pathToImage")} />`)  However, this method does not work for me.  Images only load when I use `import`. I am not sure why this is (maybe using create-react-app only allows for `import`?)